# What is Chirrut Imwe`s staff made out of?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, chirrut-imwe

We see [Chirrut Imwe](http://www.starwars.com/databank/chirrut-imwe) beat many Stormtroopers unconcious with his staff and several times pieces of armour visibly chip and shatter when struck.

Do we know exactly what Chirrut Imwe's staff is made out of?

It looks like it's wood with a possible steel grip or handle, but Chirrut hits troopers with both the steel and wooden ends so I don't think it's the grip that makes it especially powerful.

[image]

Comment: As we learned from the Ewoks, it doesn't take much more than a stick of wood to knock out a Stormtrooper.

Comment: As a side note, we can see the actor's un-post-processed eyes in this shot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the film's [Visual Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide)

> **CHIRRUT'S STAFF**
>
> *Chirrut carries a flame-hardened uneti-wood staff to help guide his path as he walks through the streets of Jedha. The top is capped with a metal lamp that contains a kyber sliver. Designed as a symbolic source of inner illumination, it also allows Chirrut to better gauge where the end of the staff is, as he can hear both the battery and crystal harmonic.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide)</sup></sub>

[image: Chirrut's Staff]

Answer (score 29):

### Wood

> She found the speaker at last, seated on the ground a few steps down
> the line of stalls. He was dressed simply, in a dark shirt and
> charcoal robe in the local style, and his smooth skin fought gamely
> against the years that infected his words. His eyes were milky and
> unfocused, and at his side lay a sturdy wooden staff in the dust. Are
> there trees left on Jedha? Jyn wondered.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

Whether it’s made of something sturdier than our puny Earth wood is uncertain, but certainly quite possible. There are woods in *Star Wars* that are quite hard, such as that of the [brylark tree](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Brylark_tree).

Comment: I'd be looking for somthing a little more specific if at all possible.

Comment: @Daft Consider refining your question.  The question title is exactly answered, the question in the main body is answered insofar as the source material is capable (unless you are asking for speculation).  The implied question, *"How does a wooden staff damage armored troops"* seems to be what you're really after, but you aren't explicitly asking it and the other two questions are answered with this answer. If you insist that the "exactly" question isn't fully answered, then consider setting objective parameters for the subjective word "exact" - species of wood, for instance, or who made it.

Comment: ^^ Or perhaps a better question would be what the stormtroopers' armor is made of.

Comment: @void_ptr Given their effectiveness, I'd say some kind of frosting.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs ... delicious, delicious frosting?

Comment: Edible stormtrooper armor... Alright let's not go there.